# Unit testing non void methods

Tags: unit-testing, methods

I am writing a application using the repository pattern. I'm currently in the view model, and want to write a unit test for a method that returns a random int. How do I go about writing a unit test for a non-void method? Would I use a mocking framework? I am not familiar with how those work. Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: you set up your test data, you call the method under test passing the test data in, you check the result of the call. This is how any test would go. If you want more help then show an actual issue

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by Andrei, it is a little tricky to answer this question as we cannot see the code and what you have tried already. However, it sounds like you are looking for a couple of pointers to help get you started.

In terms of writing a simple unit test, take a look at a recent [blog post](https://www.diffblue.com/blog/2019/11/1/the-definitive-guide-to-unit-testing-chapter-1-how-to-write-your-first-unit-test) I wrote. This is very much Java specific, however, the technique's can apply to other languages. Essentially your unit test will have the following three parts:

1. Arrange - setup your input data and the 'thing' you are looking to test.
2. Act - execute the code you are testing
3. Assert - check the result.

In your question you mention that the method returns a random int. Tests that check methods including randomness are harder to test. The best way is to mock the random behaviour so that it becomes deterministic. Here is another [blog](https://www.diffblue.com/blog/2019/11/6/the-definitive-guide-to-unit-testing-chapter-4-mocking-in-unit-tests) I have written with an example of this.

I hope that this helps. If you would like a more detailed answer then please expand on the question with example of your code and your current tests and then let me know.